# Excel VBA / Formula . Fill a range of cells with each Friday of the current month

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

So the titles a bit of a mess but im trying to do the following:

I have a range of cells from Q8:Q12, T8:T12, Q16:Q20 and T16:T20

Im trying to have these cells populate with the date for each friday of this current month. Essentially, using July (The current month) it would look something like this:

```
Q8/T8 = 06/07
Q9/T9 = 13/07
Q10/T10 = 20/07
Q11/T11 = 27/07
Q12/T12 = -
```

The reason Q/T12 would be blank is to handle months of the year that have 5 fridays in them rather than 4. Its kind of a way of error handling.

I have a cell that currently tracks the month within the Cell A9 and the formula looks like this:

```
=TEXT(NOW(),"mmmm")
```

Im not quite sure how to handle this logically really. Either VBA or a Formula would do in my eyes.

Ideally, because i have a different sheet for every month July, August etc. The formula above changes depending on what month it is currently. I would need to convert the Formula/VBA script from cells Q8:Q12 OR A9 into a value AFTER populating the date range cells Q8:Q12.

Anyone have any ideas. Im sorry its a bit of a messy question

Comment: This is tagged with both VBA and Excel formula. Is there an implementation that you'd *prefer* of the two?

Comment: In all honesty, i have no preference. If i was to choose one id probably go VBA as i can understand it a little easier than formulas. Whichever option is easier though

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[excel-formula](/questions/tagged/excel-formula)

Put this in the first cell and copy down 5

```
=IFERROR(AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW(INDEX(A:A,EOMONTH(TODAY(),-1)+1):INDEX(A:A,EOMONTH(TODAY(),0)))/(WEEKDAY(ROW(INDEX(A:A,EOMONTH(TODAY(),-1)+1):INDEX(A:A,EOMONTH(TODAY(),0))),1)=6),ROW(1:1)),"-")
```

Then format to your specifications.

There are probably more elegant formulas but this is what came to mind.

[image]

Comment: This is literally perfect. I mean, its really long but it does exactly what i need it to. Will this change when the month changes to august? Im assuming I will need to convert to value afterwards. I could do that with a button/VBA script so wouldnt be an issue.

Comment: The `TODAY()` reference todays date, so yes when it becomes Aug the data will change.  You can replace the `TODAY()` with a cell reference in which you put a date and it will use that month/year.

Comment: Thats fine, ive added a button that will be pressed at the start of each month to convert the cells into .values :)

Answer (score 3):

Here is a macro version without needing a date value in Range("A9")...

```
Dim SoM As Date
Dim EoM As Date
Dim rw As Long

SoM = DateSerial(Year(Now), Month(Now) + 0, 1)

EoM = DateSerial(Year(Now), Month(Now) + 1, 0)

rw = 8
While SoM < EoM
    If Weekday(SoM) = vbFriday Then
        Cells(rw, 17).Value = SoM
        Cells(rw, 17).NumberFormat = "m/d/yyyy"
        rw = rw + 1
    End If
    SoM = SoM + 1
Wend
```

Comment: why not make it a udf that takes in a day of week that you want and spits out number

Comment: Yes, i agree, but I was just offering a simple vba solution

Comment: Thank you very much for this. Its Appreciated. I will see if i can implement this in. May be a little easier than a formula bound cell

Answer (score 2):

I made a user defined function that works with any date range, then show how it could be applied to this example with a few formulas. This would account for year to year transitions.

[image]

```
Function DAYOFWEEKFREQUENCY(ByVal dayOfWeekType As String, ByVal startDate As String, ByVal endDate As String) As Long
    Dim myStartDate As Date
        myStartDate = CDate(startDate)

    Dim myEndDate As Date
        myEndDate = CDate(endDate)

    Dim includeStartDate As Long
        includeStartDate = 1

    Dim daysBetweenDatesInclusive As Long
        daysBetweenDatesInclusive = Application.WorksheetFunction.Days(endDate, startDate) + includeStartDate

    Dim vbStartDay As Long
        vbStartDay = Weekday(startDate)

    Dim dateCheckedIncremented As Date
        dateCheckedIncremented = myStartDate

    For dayCounter = 1 To daysBetweenDatesInclusive
        If Weekday(dateIncrementedChecked) = dayOfWeekType Then
            DAYOFWEEKFREQUENCY = DAYOFWEEKFREQUENCY + 1
        End If
        dateIncrementedChecked = DateAdd("d", 1, dateIncrementedChecked)
    Next
End Function
```

Comment: Thank you for this. I will see what i can do with it. Its appreciated